# How to remove blank space between image and text inside the JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to develop a little application for my Java class. I'm using `jsoup` to get information from an URL.

I finally got everything, but I don't know *how to remove this huge blank between the images and the text*. Any advice?

[image]

```
JFrame jf4 = new JFrame("¡¡NEWS WITH PICTURE!!");
JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
p3.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 0, 0));
p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(90, 2, 5, 5));

for (Element link: pictures) {

    Element picture = link.select("source[media=(max-width: 48em)]").first();
    Element text = link.select("img").first();
    //System.out.println(picture);  
    //System.out.println(picture.attr("data-original-set"));
    try {
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
        label3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL(picture.attr("data-original-set"))).getImage().getScaledInstance(300, 300, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
        p3.add(label3);

        JLabel label4 = new JLabel(text.attr("alt"));
        p3.add(label4);

    } catch (Exception exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(exp);
    }
} // IN CASE OF ERROR OF THE URL IT PRINTS java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: LINK TRIED

JScrollPane panelPane2 = new JScrollPane(p3);
jf4.getContentPane().add(panelPane2);
jf4.pack();
jf4.setVisible(true);
jf4.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Are all of the images the same size?  Is one of them wide enough to make the entire column that wide?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial on [Swing container layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). Why do you have border layout and grid layout on `JPanel` `p3`?

Comment: Instead of using a two column gridlayout, you can add images and text in a single column by doing this: The `JLabel` can have both image and text at the same time. Try using `p3.setIcon(...); p3.setText("Image description...");`. See [JLabel's API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html).

Comment: @VGR They are all the same size. I scale all of them

Comment: @prasad_ I'll try to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally thanks to @prasad_ I get the solution.

I follow his advice. Instead of creating a new JLabel I use the propiertie setText on the same label.

Instead of this:

```
 JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
 label3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL(picture.attr("data-original-set"))).getImage().getScaledInstance(300, 300, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
 p3.add(label3);
 JLabel label4 = new JLabel(text.attr("alt"));
 p3.add(label4);
```

I do this:

```
JLabel label3 = new JLabel();          
label3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL(picture.attr("data-original-set"))).getImage().getScaledInstance(300, 300, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
label3.setText(text.attr("alt"));
p3.add(label3);
```

So finally, the blank disappear.